# Desktop background obstructing icons

Tags: windows-7, desktop

I've been experiencing the following problem on Windows 7.

Folder icons being obstructed by the background:

[image]

Click and Drag selection box being cut, starting from a specific point:

[image]

Has anyone ever experienced this?

Answer (score 2):

It's almost like you have an invisible tool bar sitting in that spot.  Give this a try.  Go and download [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) and run it.

Once running there is a Target Icon:[image]

Click and hold that target and drag it over the area.  If it finds a running process it will show it in the list of processes in Process Explorer.  (Did I say process to many times :) )

You can then kill / uninstall the program that is running in that spot (if there is one...)